# XML Query to save client gender data in CRM2011

Tags: xml, soap, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to save a dataset into the CRM2011 by using the SOAP API.

Hopefully someone can explain how to save connected data, like gender.

Under is the update xml for a minmum of data. Gender is set in optionsets as 1->male, 2->female. I then need the xmlns and type for this data.

A normal UPDATE set look like this:

UPDATE:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <Execute xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <request i:type="a:UpdateRequest" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
        <a:Parameters xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
            <b:key>Target</b:key>
            <b:value i:type="a:Entity">
              <a:Attributes>
                <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <b:key>accountid</b:key>
                  <b:value i:type="c:guid" xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">5e7cd540-3098-e011-91cf-1cc1de6dbadb</b:value>
                </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <b:key>name</b:key>
                  <b:value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">Test D2</b:value>
                </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
                  <b:key>accountnumber</b:key>
                  <b:value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">777</b:value>
                </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
              </a:Attributes>
              <a:EntityState i:nil="true" />
              <a:FormattedValues />
              <a:Id>5e7cd540-3098-e011-91cf-1cc1de6dbadb</a:Id>
              <a:LogicalName>account</a:LogicalName>
              <a:RelatedEntities />
            </b:value>
          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
        </a:Parameters>
        <a:RequestId i:nil="true" />
        <a:RequestName>Update</a:RequestName>
      </request>
    </Execute>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: If your comment is the answer to your question then you should post it as an answer and accept your own answer when you are allowed. This will make it more helpful for other visitors

Comment: Removed own comment and posted as answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question:

```
<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
   <c:key>EntityMoniker</c:key>
   <c:value i:type="a:EntityReference">
      <a:Id>' + id + '</a:Id>
      <a:LogicalName>' + logicalName + '</a:LogicalName>
      <a:Name i:nil="true" />
   </c:value>
</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
   <c:key>State</c:key>
   <c:value i:type="a:OptionSetValue">
      <a:Value>0</a:Value>
   </c:value>
</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
```